# Все ли windows программы используют WinAPI косвенно или непосредственно?

Tags: winapi, windows

Я имею ввиду программы, не написанные на языке низкого уровня.
Программы, написанные на языке низкого уровня, вроде работают напрямую с железом. 
Непосредственно это писать на C/C++ и использовать WinAPI функции. Хотя наверно есть еще языки, которые такое могут.
А косвенно это библиотеки, framework'и, языки(например, C#). 
Конечно, могу ошибаться насчет всего, что написал.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В конечном счете, все программы Windows косвенно используют Windows API (транслируются в код, вызывающий API). Поскольку всякий запускаемый код на Windows имеет конкретную форму выполнения: это оконное приложение, консольное приложение, библиотека DLL, системная служба, эти привязки могут отличаться, но так или иначе для доступа к устройствам через HAL нужны системные функции.

Comment: Т.е. можно ли сказать, что программирование прямо через WinAPI(например, проект типа Win32 в MS Visual Studio) пока существует Windows не "вымрет" и будут востребованы специалисты со знанием WinAPI?
Просто я начал учить WinAPI(язык C++) и хотелось бы знать есть ли толк в этом.

Comment: самый главный вопрос: зачем тебе изучать winapi. с какой целью? 

познакомиться? есть конкретная область, в которой хочешь работать, используя winapi? есть идеи по тому, на каком тестовом проекте, полезном для тебя или кого-то знакомого будешь проводить изучение?   есть ли у тебя ответы на эти вопросы? ;)

Comment: У меня не ответов. Я начинающий программист и, к сожалению, еще не работаю и не знаю точно, что изучать. Что еще изучать кроме WinAPI? Qt? Я не хочу пока с этим связываться, потому что не знаю, для каких задач нужен Qt. Больше ничего такого "крупного" не припомню. Пока меня интересует GDI в WinAPI для одной маленькой игры и GUI(формы) для нескольких идей, в которых еще наверно базы данных будут использоваться, для которых можно использовать WinAPI.

Comment: @chevchelios,

     через WinAPI(например, проект типа Win32 в MS Visual Studio) пока существует Windows не "вымрет" и будут востребованы специалисты со знанием WinAPI? 

Не сказал бы. WinApi может потеснить альтернативный инструментарий - WinRT, который уже поддерживается в Win8

Comment: @Аsen смотря в чем и для кого потеснить.На большой процент рынка наврятли стоит расчитывать.